# Conditionally pass prop into component in React

Tags: reactjs

I was learning React and have the following component:

```
<DialogActions
  upperLine
  className={isNewDataSource ? classes.dialogActions : ''}
   > </DialogActions>
```

If I pass upperLine, it gives certain styles to component. But the question is if it is possible to pass upperLine conditionally like {isNewDataSource && upperLine} if I use this code then I get the error of upperLine cannot be found thus I need your help.

Comment: `upperLine={isNewDataSource}`

Comment: when a prop is defined like that, its AFAIK/normally, a `boolean` thus you can just say make it conditional by `upperLine={false}`, or `upperLine={someBooleanProperty}`

Comment: @Sukich.... this leads me to believe theres another issue here...  "if I use this code then I get the error of upperLine cannot be found"

Can you please provide the `propTypes` of  `DialogActions `?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do `upperLine={false}`.

Otherwise, you can use some smart object destructuring, like this:

```
{upperLine && ...{ upperLine: YOURVALUE }}
```

This way the prop will only get passed if it evaluates to true (has a value).

Comment: @Sukich Did you see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to conditionally pass/not pass a prop is to do this

```
<DialogActions
  {...(myCondition ? { upperLine: "whatever value you want" } : {})}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming that** `upperLine` **is a valid propType of** `DialogActions`.

When a property is defined at the implementation with no value,
E.g:

```
<DialogActions
  upperLine  <------ // like this
/>
```

Its as far as I know/normally, a `boolean` property's shorthand, (which defaults to `true`) thus you can just say make it conditional by doing the following:

```
<DialogActions
  upperLine={false}  <------ // or true, or supply a property to bind to
/>
```